# Rackspace Email Apps API retrieving customer status (enable / disable)

Tags: api, rackspace

I've read through the RackSpace API documentation, and I can `enable` and `disable` "Customers" effectively and all works.  However, I am unable to find in the [DOCUMENTATION](http://api-wiki.apps.rackspace.com/api-wiki/index.php/Customer_%28Rest_API%29) how to **check** whether a customer *is* enabled / disabled.

My way of **enabling** a customer is:

```
$client = new ApiClient();
$format = 'application/json';
$fields = Array();
$disable = $client->post(
    '/customers/xxxxxxxxx/enable',
    $fields,
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

And that works great.  --  My question is, how do I **check** via account number **if** the customer **is** enabled?  Even if there is a round-about way of checking, but I have gone through the docs, and tried even checking other aspects of the account to see if something changes during `enable` / `disable` ..  Does someone know of exact syntax, or know of a "back way" to do this?

It seems odd that it will allow you to `enable` and `disable` customers, but give you no way to **check if they are already** `enabled` / `disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query this information via the API as indicated in the JSON response here:

http://api-wiki.apps.rackspace.com/api-wiki/index.php?title=Rackspace_Mailbox_(Rest_API)#Show

You will notice a field for enabled that will read as either true = enable or false = disabled.

Comment: I thought this was the right answer at first.. But I am looking to see whether the **customer** is enabled -- Not the individual mailboxes.  When a customer has 150 plus boxes, it's a real "to do" to shut them all off and back on etc etc it's easier to disable at the customer level.

Comment: My work-around so-far is to export a csv of the customer account .. import that into db, and track enabled disabled along with the api via the db.